# AngularJS ng-animate errors after TweenMax tween

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-animate

I am working on setting up a Javascript animation so i can do a slide animation. I need to do this in Javascript because i want to set the parent and parent parent to different properties so that they allow sliding when two slides are in there, for a smooth animation.

I am running into the problem that for some reason ng-animate is erroring about some sort of object which needs to be a function.

```
object is not a function
at http://anybet.kenneth.og/wp-content/themes/dev/js/components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:558:35
```

and after a bit, when it still hasnt removed views, it tends to get worse, obviously

```
TypeError: object is not a function
at http://anybet.kenneth.og//wp-content/themes/dev/js/components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:558:35
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (http://anybet.kenneth.og//wp-content/themes/dev/js/components/angular/angular.js:324:11)
at Object.cancel (http://anybet.kenneth.og//wp-content/themes/dev/js/components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:557:15)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://anybet.kenneth.og//wp-content/themes/dev/js/components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:978:38)
at HTMLDivElement.fn (http://anybet.kenneth.og//wp-content/themes/dev/js/components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5214:19)
at HTMLDivElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://anybet.kenneth.og//wp-content/themes/dev/js/components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4641:9)
at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (http://anybet.kenneth.og//wp-content/themes/dev/js/components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4309:46)
at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (http://anybet.kenneth.og//wp-content/themes/dev/js/components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4550:12)
at jQuery.fn.extend.triggerHandler (http://anybet.kenneth.og//wp-content/themes/dev/js/components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5266:24)
```

**This occurs when it tries to fire the $complete function**

Structure is like this:

```
<div class="subpages-container">
    <div class="subpages">
        <div class="subpage slide-animation" ui-view="subpage" title="{{activeUrl}}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My slide animation looks like this at the moment:

```
do( $app = angular.module('anybetApp') ) ->


'use strict'


###*
 * Slide animation for use with ng-animate that listens to .slide-aniamtion
 * @return {Object} Gives back a Object that is compatible with ng-animate and injects
###

$app.animation '.slide-animation', ->

    leave: ( $el, $complete ) ->

        TweenMax.fromTo( $el, .2, { x: '-100%' }, { x: '0%', onComplete: $complete } )
```

It used to contain more and actually work, but i have made it very, very small and tried to figure out what is going on but have been unable to.

The $complete() works if i do this

```
do( $app = angular.module('anybetApp') ) ->


'use strict'


###*
 * Slide animation for use with ng-animate that listens to .slide-aniamtion
 * @return {Object} Gives back a Object that is compatible with ng-animate and injects
###

$app.animation '.slide-animation', ->

    leave: ( $el, $complete ) ->

        $complete()
```

Which obviously doesnt help much.

It feels as though its trying to fire a cancel event or something which is not available and gets a object instead. It confuses the hell out of me cause i cannot figure out where this error seems to be originating from. Does anyone else have had a similar problem?

Cheers and thanks!

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Ill try sometime later, i tried making a quick one now but i have to add quite a lot to reproduce this one. Its a weird error though and it seems to have something to do with cancel, maybe it something with the css3 animations trying to cancel this one and not finding the right property to do it on, i dont know.. Thanks though